# tweet.favorited returns false tweepy even the tweet is favorited

Tags: python, django, twitter, tweepy

I want to favorite tweets, which user hasn't tweeted yet. For the same, I wrote following:

```
     try:
        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = handleSubmit,count=retweetCount)
        for tweet in tweets:
            if not tweet.favorited:
                print tweet
                api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
            if not tweet.retweeted:
                api.retweet(tweet.id)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

But, in some cases `tweet.favorited` returns false, even if tweet is already favorited, leading to following error:

```
[{u'message': u'You have already favorited this status.', u'code': 139}]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not setting a cache in the api instance (cache!=None):

```
class API([auth_handler=None][, host='api.twitter.com'][, search_host='search.twitter.com'][, cache=None][, api_root='/1'][, search_root=''][, retry_count=0][, retry_delay=0][, retry_errors=None][, timeout=60][, parser=ModelParser][, compression=False][, wait_on_rate_limit=False][, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=False][, proxy=None])
```

It can be twitter's cache, thing I doubt or that the call is returning repeated ids. Try printing all the tweets ids to check that all tweets are different and check if after the `api.create_favorite(tweet.id)` the favorited attribute changes.

By the way, the tweet (status model) has a built-in method to favourite itself. You can perform tweet.favorite() to favorite the tweet.

```
class Status(Model):
...
    def favorite(self):
        return self._api.create_favorite(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet if this is a problem with Twitter's API or Tweepy's wrapper, but it doesn't seem to be cache related. A workaround is to make an extra call to the method statuses_lookup, which returns the favorited property correctly, before actually calling the create_favorite method. However, this approach is less efficient than just throwing an error because you would make two API calls when the tweet hasn't been favorited.